# Cannot access props from inside navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I am using the `StackNavigator` library but cannot figure out how to access the props from within navigationOptions.

In my calling class I have:

```
navigate("TestView", { mdata: mdataObject })
```

In my TestView class I have the following:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: this.props.navigation.state.params.mdata.title
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot find property 'navigation' of undefined

I have confirmed that I can access `this.props.navigation.state.params.mdata.title` from the componentDidMount() function so there is data there.

Why am I getting this error from within the navigationOptions function and what can I do to fix it?

Also, I called navigateOptions a function, but not sure that is correct. What should I be calling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access navigation props at navigationOptions:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: navigation.state.params.mdata.title // your case
})
```

Comment: Thank you. If the component does mount before receiving the navigation params will this eventually be invoked or will it just not get a tittle?

Comment: It will be invoked.

Comment: Hmm, this was working earlier, now when I try it again I get the following: `Error: 'title' cannot be defined as a function in navigation options for 'TestView' screen. Any ideas what the issue could be?